# Printing a Table with 4 columns for conversions between ft to yds

Tags: c

I want to create a table that has 4 columns like below:

Feet-------Yards-----------------Yards------Feet

---

Currently my code only allows me to make 2 separate tables to display both conversions from feet to yards in one table, and yards to feet in another table. I am not sure how to make it work to display all 4 conversions at once in 4 columns. I am assuming an array and maybe a for loop instead of a while loop?

Here's my code, note I want to display from 0 to 100 yards/feet. So lower limit is 0 and upper limit is 100.

```
int upperLimit = 100;
int lowerLimit = 0;
int interval = 5;
float yards = 0;
float feet = 0;

void toYards()
{
  feet = lowerLimit;
  while(feet <= upperLimit)
  {
     yards = feet / 3;
     printf("\n%3.0f %20.1f", feet, yards);
     feet = feet + interval;
  }
}

void toFeet()
{
  yards = lowerLimit;
  while(yards <= upperLimit)
  {
     feet = yards * 3 ;
     printf("\n%3.0f %20.1f", yards, feet);
     yards = yards + interval;
  }
}

void displayFeet()
{
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("Yards \t Feet");
  printf("\n----------------------------");
}

void displayYards()
{
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("Feet \t Yards");
  printf("\n----------------------------");
}
```

Comment: I don't see your variables feet and yards declared anywhere .... are they global scope variables ?

Comment: @m.raynal yes, they come earlier in the code.

Comment: In `printf("\n%3.0f %20.1f", feet, yards);` I am intrigued why you have a smaller field width for feet as for yards, since there are more feet than yards. Note: best to format the column headings to the same width that you format their data.

Comment: inside the loop, neither `yards` nor `feet` get incremented so the condition of the loops is always true.

Comment: "_display from 0 to 100 yards/feet_" Yard or feet. Pick one; can't have both from 0 to 100.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir added that piece of code I was missing.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie well one half of the table shows 0 to 100 yards as in feet, the other half of the table shows 0 to 100 feet as in yards.

Comment: How to you make all four columns side by side in the same iteration? By stepping a *number* from 0 to 100 and printing the conversion of that number of feet as yards and that number of yards as feet, on the same line.

Comment: Fill two arrays from 0..100, one for feet, one for yards. Then print the tables along each other.

Comment: put  `printf("\n %f \t %f \t %f \t %f ", i, i/3, i, 3*i);` in a while loop ; that's incredibly lazy a way, but it might do the job

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display both yard -> feet and feet -> yard in same row (in one table), you need to do `printf` of 4 columns, not two. Accordingly, you will have to change your functions. See following for the hint:

```
void printFeetNYardTables()
{
  int unit = lowerLimit;
  while(unit <= upperLimit)
  {
     printf("\n%3.0f %20.1f %3.0f %20.1f", unit, toYards(unit), unit, toFeet(unit));
     unit++;
  }
}

double toYards(int feet)
{
  return (double) feet/3.0;
}

double toFeet(int yards)
{
  return (double) yards*3.0;
}
```